# Logarithm Expansion Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you expand the following logarithm:
$$ \log_5 \left(\frac{u}{v^3}\right)^6 $$

The result I got was:
$$ 6\log_5u -18\log_5v $$

Is that fully expanded?

Comment: Looks about right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct!!!

$$\log_5 \left ( \frac{u}{v^3}\right )^6=6 \cdot \log_5 \left (\frac{u}{v^3} \right) \\= 6 \cdot (\log_5(u)- \log_5(v^3))=6 \cdot (\log_5 u-3 \log_5 v)=6\log_5 u-18 \log_5 v $$

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean $\log_5 ((\frac{u}{v^3})^6)$ or $(\log_5 (\frac{u}{v^3}))^6$? If it is the former your answer is correct; if it is the latter it simplifies to $(\log_5 (u)-3\log_5(v))^6$ instead.